# Get-MsolPasswordPolicy unknown error occured

Tags: powershell, office365

I cant seems to find the root cause of this error:

```
Get-MsolPasswordPolicy : Unknown error occurred.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MsolPasswordPolicy
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Get-MsolPasswordPolicy], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.DomainNotRootException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.GetPasswordPolicy
```

Basically, I ran this command `Get-MsolPasswordPolicy -DomainName test.example.com` and got the error above.

But I am able to run the command with root domain: example.com

Both domains are verified. I am wondering if the command is applicable to subdomain.

Anyone met with this before?

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a password policy for subdomains.

Subdomains get the policy of their root domains.

To get all the domains for which a password policy is assignable, try the following command:

```
Get-MsolDomain | Where {$_.Status -eq "Verified" -and !$_.RootDomain } | select Name
```